# Wordpress - Displaying content from custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im using advanced custom fields and have setup a custom post type for testimonials, on the testimonial page there is a relationship field (display_on_page) where you would select which page to display the testimonial on.

The issue is that the testimonial displays on everypage when a page is chosen

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong on the below please?

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=Testimonial'); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php $posts = get_field('display_on_page');

        if( $posts ): ?>
            <?php the_field('the_testimonial'); ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you should *check* if the value that you get from `get_field('display_on_page')` matches the *current page ID*. 
(I'm assuming that the page ID is what is stored by the custom field you created).

If that's the case, you may [query your posts filtering by custom field values](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/), like such:

```
<?php 

// Fetches current page ID, assuming that this is page.php or similar
$current_page_id = get_the_ID();

query_posts(
    'post_type=Testimonial',
    'meta_key' => 'display_on_page',
    'meta_value' => $current_page_id // Only gets Testimonials that are set for this page
); 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    the_field('the_testimonial');
endwhile;

// Resets default WP Post Data *AFTER* the loop is complete
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```